# Create a child job from a parent "seed" job with Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am an IT student and I need help with my school project.

I am trying to build a *freeStyleJob* that takes 2 parameters : a GitHub Repository and a Display Name to create a child job that automatically executes tests on that repository. The parent parameters should be set in stone in the childs' environment.
Everything must be defined in a single *job_dsl.groovy* file.

The child job is at *root* while the parent is inside the *Tools* folder.

The problem I am facing is creating a "*template*" for that child job.

Here is my current job_dsl.groovy file :

```
def seedTemplate = { seedTemplate ->
    freeStyleJob("seed_template") {
    properties {
        githubProjectUrl('https://github.com/"$GITHUB_NAME"')
    }
    triggers {
        cron("H/1 * * * *")
        githubPush()
    }
    wrappers {
        preBuildCleanup {
            deleteDirectories()
                cleanupParameter('CLEANUP')
                }
        }
    steps {
        shell('ls')
        shell('make')
    }       //steps
    }       //freeStyle
}       //seedTemplate

freeStyleJob('/Tools/SEED') {
    parameters {
        stringParam("GITHUB_NAME",
                    null,
                    "GitHub repository owner/repo_name (e.g.: \"EpitechIT31000/chocolatine\")")
        stringParam("DISPLAY_NAME",
                    null,
                    "Display name for the job")
    }
    steps {
        dsl {
            external("seedTemplate")
        }       //dsl
     }      //steps
}       //freeStyle
```

I am uncertain about the dsl step although I think it might be my best chance of success.
I found what I believe to be 2 useful dsl methods in the documentation: "external" and "text".

- External reads a DSL script present in the same workspace as the freeStyleJob, but **how can I define a child job with the correct environment (defined in the parent parameters) without the job being created at the same time as the parent job ?**
- Text generate the job based on a string, but it seems too redundant and barbarian to be helpful as I CANNOT use another file that the *job_dsl.groovy*

When I execute the groovy file, only the *SEED* freeStyleJob is generated and it runs successfully, but I get the following error when I run the child job :

```
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Tools/SEED
ERROR: no Job DSL script(s) found at seed_template.groovy
```

Thank you to everyone who took the time to read my *(stupid ?)* question.